# React custom component with conditional type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My target is to allow other developers to apply a click handler for a button, on click event, **only if the button's type is `button`**.

User can set only `button` or `submit` type.

I don't want to allow developer to set `onClick` property on the component when `type` is `submit`.

I have the following custom component:

```
import React, { type ReactNode, type ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

import { concatDiverseClasses } from '@/utils/component';

import EDSvg from '../EDSvg';
import type icons from '../../../assets/icons';

import classes from './EDAcceptButton.module.scss';

interface IBaseProps<
    ButtonType = Extract<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>['type'], 'button' | 'submit'>,
> {
    readonly className?: string;
    readonly type: ButtonType;
    readonly disabled: boolean;
    readonly iconName?: keyof typeof icons;
    readonly children?: ReactNode;
}

type IProps<ButtonType = Extract<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>['type'], 'button' | 'submit'>> =
    ButtonType extends 'submit'
        ? IBaseProps
        : IBaseProps & {
                readonly onClick: VoidFunction;
          };

const EDAcceptButtonView: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    if (props.type === 'submit') {
        return (
            <button
                className={concatDiverseClasses(classes['container'], props.className)}
                type="submit"
                disabled={props.disabled}
            >
                {props.iconName ? (
                    <>
                        <span className={classes['container__text']}>{props.children}</span>
                        <EDSvg className={classes['container__icon']} name={props.iconName} />
                    </>
                ) : (
                    props.children
                )}
            </button>
        );
    }

    return (
        <button
            className={concatDiverseClasses(classes['container'], props.className)}
            type="button"
            disabled={props.disabled}
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            {props.iconName ? (
                <>
                    <span className={classes['container__text']}>{props.children}</span>
                    <EDSvg className={classes['container__icon']} name={props.iconName} />
                </>
            ) : (
                props.children
            )}
        </button>
    );
};

EDAcceptButtonView.displayName = 'EDAcceptButtonView';
EDAcceptButtonView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(EDAcceptButtonView);
```

But I get an error

```
Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<IBaseProps<"submit" | "button"> | (IBaseProps<"submit" | "button"> & { readonly onClick: VoidFunction; })>'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IBaseProps<"submit" | "button"> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)
```

Also, when I try to use this component outside:

```
                        <EDAcceptButton
                            className={classes['formActions__submit']}
                            type="submit"
                            disabled={!props.isSecretLabelValid}
                            onClick={() => {}}
                        >
```

Typescript allows me to apply `onClick` propety. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pass a type argument to `IBaseProps`, which means that each of the object types in the union created by `IProps` has a `type` property that is a union (and can't be used to discriminate).

If you pass the `ButtonType` to `IBaseProps`, it works as expected:

```
type IProps<ButtonType = Extract<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>['type'], 'button' | 'submit'>> =
    ButtonType extends 'submit'
        ? IBaseProps<ButtonType>
        : IBaseProps<ButtonType> & {
                readonly onClick: VoidFunction;
          };
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecYCeYSiqGAchACZLaHFwBCArjDBAHYASAKgLIAZAIJsowAEaskAZzgBfOADMoEEHADkUMjHUBuAFD7QkWLjhpOaFDAAiwAG5Io0pAGEANimkvZC5ao0AAQB6VmB3aWCLcE4kDh0DIxjTAFEbAGV7AHMlFTV1ADoC4LTMrL0kk3h6EmALDll-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-dJy6Dfo36Xv5ldgbg+6If0UDDDSGY5gWDUEOQhLDTATwCDK351BT6D07gzOkIqYu09g0ly4SpBjg2GAT3Y3Ak6AA) (has some errors due to missing imports, but these don't affect the solution)